# Detect Chrome browser window width and height to prevent element overflow

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css

I'm looking for a code that either:

Prevents an element from extending beyond the edge of a window.
OR 
Detects the window width or height so that the element's width/height may be set in units of px.

This code only needs to work in Google Chrome.

I've done a LOT of research and everything looks so complicated.  Isn't there a simple CSS solution?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: There may be a CSS solution, but knowing a little more of your DOM would help...

Comment: sure.  I have a header bar across the entire top, and then two divisions side by side extending all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If you could have a short example of your problem on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net it would help...

Comment: <table style="width:100%;height:80px;"><div1 style="height:???;width:20%;"><div2 style="height:???;width:80%;float:right;">

Comment: Are you trying to create a popup overlay by chance?

Comment: It's just the basic layout I described above.  I don't know how to make the DIV's the right height so that they don't go below the browser window.  I went them exactly to stop at the bottom of the browser window

Comment: You could just add a wrapper around your whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem that jQuery solved for me,

```
var width = jQuery(window).width();
```

there's also a .height() method

Comment: The thing is that there's usually a way to do things without using javascript, so it would be nice to see the full issue before coming to conclusions like this.

Comment: Well said!  Right on target.  Do things without JavaScript when they involve layout and formatting :)

Comment: Well, I ended up doing something like this even though I didn't want to...  I'm waiting for CSS4 :) :) :) ...